# visual studio sql DB adds whitespaces

Tags: asp.net, sql, sql-server, visual-studio

I'm working with VS2010 and asp.net and build a SQL Server Database with some int and char values.

My problem is, that the char(50) automatically fills the unused chars with whitespaces like:

```
"foo           "
```

What can i do to get only "foo"?

Comment: Yes, that's the way CHAR(x) is defined in SQL Server - use VARCHAR instead if you want to have string only as long as needed. See the SQL Server Books Online documentation: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176089.aspx

Answer (score 7):

Change it to varchar(50). The char(50) data type will fill the remaining characters of the field with spaces.

Answer (score 2):

It's not Visual Studio that's adding the white spaces, but your datatype.

Char is fixed-length, while varchar is variable length.  Char will pad the remaining text with spaces up to your field length.

You can see more information about SQL datatypes [here](http://www.sql-server-helper.com/faq/data-types-p01.aspx).